Reshuffling and Fubini's theorem
Suppose I have an absolutely convergent series
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k x^{E_k}
$$
but the sequence $\{E_k\}$ of positive real numbers is not nice: it will contains accumulation points and infinitely repeated elements. Can I nevertheless write my series as:
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty b_n x^{h_n}
$$
with the sequence $\{h_n\}$ consisting of distinct elements?
My idea was to traverse $\{E_k\}$ and extract the distinct elements from it, which defines $\{h_n\}$. (Is there a canonical name for such a subsequence?) Then I add another index $m$ that counts the occurrences of each $h_n$, so we get an invertible map from $k$ to $(n,m)$ and the original series becomes something like
$$
\sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty c_{n,m} x^{h_n}
$$
where the $c_{n,m} = a_{k(n,m)}$ or zero (for example for sufficiently large $m$ if a given $h_n$ does not repeat infinitely often). Then I use Fubini to split the double sum into two parts and let $b_n = \sum_m c_{n,m}$. Am I missing some condition on the $\{E_k\}$ or is this always an allowed operation?
